# ASP.NET Core 5 MVC and OpenID Connect - error when hosting on remote Windows server

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, openid-connect

I've run into trouble getting my ASP.NET Core 5 MVC web app to run on a remote Windows 2019 server.

I've created a sample test app, with the "MS Identity" authentication scheme, which uses OpenID Connect to authenticate users against our company Azure AD.

This is my `Startup.cs` for clarification:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    List<string> initialScopes = new List<string>();
    string scope = Configuration.GetValue<string>("MyAPI:Scopes");

    services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
            options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
        });

    services.AddRazorPages()
            .AddMvcOptions(options => { })
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
}
```

I have an app registration in our company Azure tenant (and all relevant info about this is in `appsettings.json`, in the `AzureAd` section), and locally, this works just fine - when I hit the `http://localhost:1234/` URL, I get prompted by Azure AD for my credentials, and after I provide them, I get logged in and my claims are set up correctly - all seems fine (and `http://localhost:1234/signin-oidc` has been setup as a callback path in the Azure AD app registration).

Now I deployed this to a Windows 2019 server - old school, by publishing from Visual Studio to a folder, and copying all those files to the remote Win2019 server manually. I set up an IIS application, pointing to that directory - all seems fine.

But when I try to hit my remote URL `https://myserver.mycompany.org/myapp`, I get an error **http 403 - forbidden** for the OpenID Connect callback path - `https://myserver.mycompany.org/myapp/signin-oidc`.

And yes - I *have* set up this URL as a "callback" URL in my Azure app registration - but I still get an http 403 forbidden. Any ideas why? Do I need to do an extra step in the remote IIS config to allow the MS Identity subsystem to do the OIDC callback to the `./signin-oidc` path?

(PS: the same error occurs when I'm trying to deploy any of the Microsoft sample apps for OpenId Connect and ASP.NET Core - found on Github here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2. Since I don't think MS would publish code that doesn't actually work, I'm sure I must be missing a step or two when deploying / setting up my app in IIS on the remote server)

Comment: What's the identity of application pool? What's the substatus code of 403?

Comment: @BruceZhang: I don't see any substatus code of the http403 - just http 403 - forbidden - nothing more. The app pool uses that standard "AppPoolIdentity" - nothing fancy

Comment: 403 indicates that there is no permission, authorization fail, but the authentication is successful. So did you use authentication? What identity is used for authentication? Try to change identity of application to admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was due to the configuration inheritance in my IIS.

I had a first ASP.NET Core app in the "root" of the IIS site - which of course has a `web.config` that looks something like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" 
             modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyRootApp.dll" 
                stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
</system.webServer>
```

Then, in my `MyApp` IIS application, located "below" the root of the "Default Site", I had a second ASP.NET Core app, which of course again has a `web.config` that defines another `handler` - and this caused the confusion.

I found a post somewhere on the interwebs after **a lot** of searching that provided the solution - modify the `web.config` to apply the settings only to the app's own directory - and not inherit it down to children; by using the `<location>` XML element as shown here:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" 
                 modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyRootApp.dll" 
                    stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```